# Android - Regroup Google Map Markers

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

On my Android App, I've got a map with a lot of markers.
But when the user is zooming out, it hard the see the differents markers.
So I want to regroup then in one when there are a two much markers.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the open source clustering libraries for Google Maps Android API v2: [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) (demo [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.demo)) or [Clusterkraf](https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf) (demo [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twotoasters.clusterkraf.sample)).

Answer (score 0):

For who is having troubles with *Clusterkraf* (I can't make it work!) and for who can't use *android-maps-extension* cause it's shipped with a custom build of Play Services lib, I want to suggest this other library, that is tiny, well written and works out of the box:

> **Clusterer**: https://github.com/mrmans0n/clusterer

After a whole morning spent trying using the other two libs, this one saved my day!